# How to clear the previous query result on a list (in Prolog)

Tags: list, prolog

I have this code:

```
connected(a,b).
connected(b,a).
connected(b,j).
connected(j,b).
connected(j,i).
connected(i,j).
connected(i,h).
connected(h,i).
connected(h,g).
connected(g,h).
connected(g,f).
connected(f,g).
connected(g,k).
connected(k,g).
connected(f,k).
connected(k,f).
connected(k,e).
connected(e,k).
connected(k,d).
connected(d,k).
connected(e,d).
connected(d,e).
connected(d,c).
connected(c,d).

route(X,Y,R):-route(X,Y,[X],P),reverse(R,P).

route(X,Y,Vs,[Y|Vs]):-connected(X,Y),not_yet_visited(Y,Vs).

route(X,Y,Vs,Rs):-connected(X,Z),not_yet_visited(Z,Vs),route(Z,Y,[Z|Vs],Rs).

not_yet_visited(A,As):- \+memberchk(A,As).

is_the_same(B,C):- B=C,write('The starting room is the same with the ending room').

go(X,Y):-is_the_same(X,Y).
go(X,Y):-route(X,Y,R),writelist(R).

writelist([L]):-write(L),write('-->'),write('I am in room '),write(L).
writelist([L|Lt]):-write(L),write('-->'),writelist(Lt).
```

The execution predicate is the go/2 where I give a starting room X and an ending room Y.Route predicate calculates the path from X to Y and then it stores it to the R list.Then it prints it via the writelist predicate and the result is being showed like this:

```
go(a,d).
a-->b-->j-->i-->h-->g-->f-->k-->d-->I am in room d
```

The problem is that when I ask for an alternative solution path,it keeps the previous latest value of the list and it prints it at the beggining of the next query just like this:

```
go(a,d).
a-->b-->j-->i-->h-->g-->f-->k-->d-->I am in room d
true ;
d-->a-->b-->j-->i-->h-->g-->f-->k-->e-->d-->I am in room d
true ;
d-->a-->b-->j-->i-->h-->g-->k-->d-->I am in room d
true ;
d-->a-->b-->j-->i-->h-->g-->k-->e-->d-->I am in room d
true ;
d-->
false.
```

The starting room should be "a" for this certain example and not "d".
How can I get rid of the previous "d" value??

Comment: Why are you hiding your crucial `route` predicate from us?

Comment: Just to keep it simple but I added it now so you can see

Comment: It's tedious to have both `connected(a,b).` and `connected(b,a).` - I recommend you search for and look at the many existing route/edge examples for Prolog.

Comment: ok I will check them.As for the problem with previous value of the list on the queries?? "L" variable is keeping the previous query value.

Comment: `Vs` is your route.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is on the route.The writelist predicate just prints the ending room of the previous query list.I need somehow to clear it before the next call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and I solved it.

```
writelist([L]):-write(L),write('-->'),write('I am in room '),write(L),!.
writelist([L|Lt]):-write(L),write('-->'),writelist(Lt).
```

It needed a CUT at the end of the first writelist clause.

Comment: That makes no sense. Why are you ignoring the route list in `Vs`?